# Animate color of UIView

Tags: swift, animation

I use Swift 2 and Xcode 7.1

I wonder how to perform nested animations?
Actually i want to annimation that will change the color of my sight gradually. The view will: red -> blue -> green -> red -> ...

This is my code :

```
func animate(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        //self.lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.5)
        self.circle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.89, blue: 0.27, alpha: 1)
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                //self.lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.5)
                self.circle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.2, blue: 0.7, alpha: 1)
                }, completion: {
                    (value: Bool) in
                    self.animate()
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested of the animations you should use options of the  `UIView.animateWithDuration` they are `Repeat` and in this case `Autoreverse`

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {

           //execute animation changes hear

            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How to tell him if it should turn blue or red?